# else if statement does not get evaluated in client browser - javascript socket.io

Tags: javascript, if-statement, socket.io

I am implementing a basic chat in the style of Slack, and I am at the point where I want to give the users the option to message each other privately.

When a user sends a request for a private chat to another user and the other accepts, a button with the name of the other user should appear in each of the users' browser.

The problem is that at the moment, a button appears in each user's interface, but only the user who sent the request (user 1) gets a button with the other user's name, while the other only gets a button with no text in it. Code is as follows:

```
socket.on("setting up private chat buttons", data => {

    privateChannelButton = document.createElement('button');
    privateChannelButton.className = "new-button btn btn-dark";

    if (localStorage.getItem('userName') == data["user 1"]){

        privateChannelButton.innerHTML = data["user 2"];    
        console.log("case 1 happened");

    }

    else if (localStorage.getItem('userName') == data["user2"]) {

        privateChannelButton.innerHTML = data["user 1"];
        console.log("case 2 happened");

    }

    document.querySelector('#channels').appendChild(privateChannelButton);
});
```

If I look at what the console outputs, basically it's always "case 1 happened", as if as soon as the first condition is evaluated to true by one of the browsers, both of them skip to the next block of code which is the adding of the button. Why is this?

Comment: What does this mean? _as if as soon as the first condition is evaluated to true by one of the browsers, both of them skip_ - _EACH_ browser acts independently of one another. It is impossible for executing code in one browser to have a direct effect on a physically disconnected browser.

Comment: What is the difference between: `data["user 2"] ` and `data["user2"]`?

Comment: agreed. What I'm saying is that that's what it looks like, even though it's clearly impossible. One browser, the User 1 one gets the button showing up with the correct text, while the other gets a button with no text, and the console.log message I have put doesn't get logged at all, as if it didn't even evaluate the else if statement. it's confusing.

Comment: Finally, what happens if _neither_ is true? Defensive programming dictates we have "the final solution" - you need an `else`.

Comment: Is it the typo then?

Comment: oh my god guys, I am SO SORRY. It is the typo. I feel dumb! Also, I don't have an ultimate else statement because it is impossible that the username is anything other than either user 1 or user 2. is this wrong?

Comment: don't feel dumb. It is all good. But please consider what I said about defensive programming. If you had a final `else` that simply logged or alerted "yo! you have a problem here!" - you would have found it yourself. Get it?

Comment: ohhhh I see! that makes sense. I will try to always think about defensive programming from now on. Thank you Randy!

Comment: Technically, the final `else` in this case should actually `throw` a new Error.